# Was Hulk and Loki's fight in Avengers (2012) based on a comics battle?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk, the-avengers-2012, loki

In Marvel's *The Avengers* (2012), Hulk fights Loki towards the end of the movie (provoked by Loki's statement "I am a god, you dull creature"), smacking him into the ground several times and then commenting, "Puny god." **Was this battle *or its dialogue* based on an exchange or battle in the comics?**

*NOTE: I'm only looking for a comics reference pre-movie; anything else, obviously, could not have been the basis for it. And I'm willing to take no as an answer, as long as it's backed up.*

Comment: I am unable to find the panel or issue but I'm pretty sure that the "puny god" line is a callback to a battle in the comics between Hulk and Thor, not Loki.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a callback to that scene in *[Deadpool's Art of War #3](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Deadpool%27s_Art_of_War_Vol_1_3)* (February, 2015), but I'm pretty sure there was never a scene like that in the comics before the first Avengers movie in 2012.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm also looking into some options, this is interesting to know but as you noticed I'm definitely looking for pre-2012 stuff. This is really interesting though

Comment: Well, just to be clear, my answer is that _there's no such scene in the comics prior to 2012_. That answer is partly based on the fact that I've never seen or heard of such a scene, and I'm very familiar with both characters. Aside from that, the fact that there was a callback to that scene in a comic published _after_ the movie tends to suggest that this scene never occurred in the comics before the movie. Otherwise, the scene in the movie itself would be a callback to the comics, and it seems unlikely that a later comic would feature a callback to a callback.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll accept this unless I can find another acceptable one later. Thanks!