# LF Thor story involving (Banner green) Hulk and (traditional male adult) Loki?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, comics

[Reference this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/256890/was-hulk-and-lokis-fight-in-avengers-2012-based-on-a-comics-battle) for context.

I recall there was a comic book story involving Thor, Loki, and the Bruce Banner green Incredible Hulk, probably circa early 2000’s.

The story was likely in an issue of Thor (likely vol. 2), and specifically included the Jurgens’ bearded “Thord” era — bearded Thor’s “Lord of Asgard” costume, although less likely it could have been an issue of Hulk involving the Jurgens’ “Lord of Asgard” era Thor:
[image: Thord of Asgard]

The plot involved Loki transporting Hulk to Thor to cause him problem, and concludes with Thor returning Hulk to Loki.

A comic specific panel is the ending where Thor returns an angry Hulk to Loki who then grapples him in at least one comic panel.

Found the scene, seeking the comic:
[image: Hulk smash Loki]

Thor’s helmet is actually older than Jurgens’ “Lord of Asgard,” perhaps when Thor was using beard to hide Hela’s scars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The panel in question is from ***[Last Hero Standing #5](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Last_Hero_Standing_Vol_1_5)*** (December, 2005). This mini-series was part of the [MC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marvel_Comics_2) line of comics, set in the same alternate future ([Earth-982](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Earth-982)) that the [May 'Mayday' Parker](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/May_Parker_(Earth-982)) version of Spider-Girl is from.

[image]

Comment: That’s it! Thanks! The publication dates vs. Thor’s appearance style is messing with my mind, lol.